Why does South Korea's presidential impeachment process involve the judiciary?
The BBC reports that South Korean Parliament has voted to impeach Han Duck-Soo, the current acting president of South Korea. It also reported that the impeachment will only happen if the South Korean constitutional court also upholds it:

BBC (27 December 2024): South Korea has voted to impeach its acting president Han Duck-soo, two weeks after parliament voted to impeach its President Yoon Suk Yeol ... Korea's Constitutional Court is typically made up of a nine-member bench. At least six judges must uphold Yoon's impeachment in order for the decision to be upheld. There are currently only six judges on the bench, meaning a single rejection would save Yoon from being removed.

The Guardian has also reported that the trial of the former president Yoon Suk Yeol, for his impeachment, is also set to begin on 27 December 2024:

South Korean president Yoon Suk Yeol’s legal team are set to attend court on Friday as the constitutional court begins hearings into his impeachment by parliament over his short-lived imposition of martial law ... The court has 180 days to decide whether to reinstate Yoon or remove him. In the latter scenario, a new presidential election would be held within 60 days.

The Wikipedia page on Constitutional Court of Korea states:

For passage, the [impeachment] motion must receive the support of a two-thirds majority if it concerns the president and a simple majority for any other office. Once the impeachment motion passes the National Assembly, the Constitutional Court adjudicates the impeachment, and until the Constitutional Court renders a decision, the impeached official is suspended from office and unable to exercise power.

Involving the judiciary in a political process seems contrary to the doctrine of separation of powers in a democracy. As far as I am aware, most mature democracies tend to limit the scope of judicial review of normal legislative activities. Impeachment process, deemed to be a political process, thus also falls in the exclusive domain of the Legislature (i.e. the elected representatives are deemed to be the competent authority to adjudicate on such matters; criminal proceedings against the impeached official, if necessary, tend to be filed separately, and are often independent of the impeachment process.)
So, why does the South Korean impeachment process involve both the Legislature and the Judiciary?

Your link supporting impeachment being a (wholly) political process is to an article from a U.S. publisher, speaking specifically to the U.S. impeachment process.  There is no particular reason why similar processes in other countries should have all the same characteristics as the U.S. impeachment process.  Including to what extent the process is political, and to what extent a matter of justice.

@JohnBollinger Yes, when I posted this Q I was ignorant to the fact that impeachment is not treated as a political process by all democracies, which was honestly a bit confusing. I guess it makes sense for some to involve the judiciary too, depending on the political system they've adopted. Though, in such systems, only criminal activities will lead to impeachment, as it could ignore non-criminal "conduct unbecoming" political actions by those in positions of power (which is addressed when impeachment is purely a Legislative affair, like in the world's oldest or the world's largest democracy).

@JohnBollinger For example, one of the (many) charges against US President Andrew Johnson, during his impeachment, was also of "disrespecting the Congress" (which sounds silly until you also consider that fascist leaders do tend to disrespect political institutions).

You may wish to edit your question. When you say "impeachment", aren’t you combining the power of accusation and indictment with the power of judgement and removal from office as though they were all one and the same thing? If so, that's not universal. Even in America the body doing the indicting has no powers of trying, judging, and removing from office. That's why the House of Representatives acts only as a sort of grand jury, not a jury, whereas the Senate like any regular jury (meaning, not a grand jury) cannot indict only put on trial.

The idea that impeachment is (or should be) purely political and not judicial is a matter of opinion and political culture. Even in the United States, where this notion is prevalent, the chief justice of the Supreme Court presides. While largely symbolic, this does acknowledge the inherently judicial nature of the proceedings.
In many countries (arguably, most democracies) a high court must approve the impeachment decision to make it official (as in South Korea), and in a number of other cases, the process actually starts in the judiciary rather than the legislature. The Wikipedia article on Impeachment links to an article that asserts:

Constitutions in 9 democracies give a court—often the country's constitutional court—the power to begin an impeachment; another 61 constitutions place the court at the end of the process.


Spain is an example. The PM, ministers, PM have immunity from regular tribunals. If there are claims of involvement in crimes, the proceedings are passed to a higher tribunal. If that tribunal considers that an accusation is granted, they ask the parliament to lift the immunity. So, the trial itself is done by judges, but there is a degree of protection from politically motivated prosecution.

Note: The wikipedia quote cited about the US being a "notable exception" is not correct as in India too the impeachment of the President is purely a legislative affair. France too treats it as legislative affair. In Ireland too, the final adjudicator is the Legislature. Also, a "constitutional council" isn't necessarily a body under the judiciary, and many countries form it only when required, and some even include MPs in it making it a quasi-judicial body to assist the legislature.

Regarding the US system where the Chief Justice presides, I understand that s/he only temporarily takes over the role of the speaker / chairperson of the Senate to lend more neutrality to the proceedings. It still remains a legislative affair, with the elected representatives making the final decision on the impeachment, and the judiciary cannot overturn this decision.

@sfxedit Election of the Indian president is also primarily a legislative affair, unlike in the US, so it is arguably more like a case of a popular recall in countries that allow for that (that is, the same people who elect the president are those primarily involved in removing him before end of term). The US is very much an exception though in that neither the courts nor the people directly responsible for the election of the president are actively involved in impeachment.

@AustinHemmelgarn That's a good point I hadn't considered. Note though that this still doesn't make the US a "notable exception". The French President is also directly elected, but the impeachment process is a legislative affair.

@sfxedit The US president isn’t directly elected though, we have this insane complexity called the electoral college, and even with the current state of affairs where most electors have an absolute mandate to vote in-line with the popular vote, it’s still not a direct election by the public like the French president is.

@AustinHemmelgarn Yes, that's true. I cited the French example to highlight that just as in the US, the people who elect the President aren't involved in his impeachment / removal and it is done by the legislature, and hence the wikipedia claim that the US is a "notable exception" isn't factual. (reposted to correct a typo).

And then of course there are countries like the Netherlands where the entire process doesn't exist. There's only the option for parliament to have a vote of no confidence in the cabinet (or one of its members) which then leads to either new elections of the cabinet member being replaced. In theory the king can ask the cabinet to step down, but that's AFAIK not happened in over a century.

The Chief Justice only presides over an impeachment trial of the President, probably because the Vice President is the one who becomes President in the event of a conviction/removal.  That's an obvious conflict of interest.  (Remember that this was written when the VP was to be the runner-up in the Presidential election, and therefore a political rival of the President.)

The logic behind involving the judiciary in impeachment questions is that a directly elected president should removable only if he broke some law (or is recalled by popular referendum, i.e. a kind of reverse election), not at the arbitrary whim of the legislature, which can come up with a their own standard for "misdemeanors". Even the latter has yet to happen in practice in the US, it could happen in theory that the legislature removes the president because he has blue eyes or something. Of course, allowing the general electorate to reverse their decisions before the mandate term is up is itself a question of constitutional choice. Whether it's better or worse to have something remove at the popular whim is (also) a matter of opinion.
In the South Korean case, it seems the president can only be removed if he broke some law. The legislature acts as a filter for referring cases, but is not the ultimate decider if the president broke a law.

According to Article 65 Clause 1, if the President, Prime Minister, or other state council members violate the Constitution or other laws of official duty, the National Assembly can impeach them.
Clause 2 states the impeachment bill must be proposed by one third and approved by a majority of members of the National Assembly for passage.
By the Constitutional Court Act, the Constitutional Court must make a final decision within 180 days after it receives any case for adjudication, including impeachment cases.

There is no popular recall option in South Korean constitution.
Arguably, the proper separation of powers (if you insist on it) is that Parliament legislates, and courts apply the legislation. True, a Parliament could come up with very narrowly crafted laws to work around that like "anybody called Yoon must be removed from office immediately". But that's less likely to happen because of how silly it looks to the public which also votes in the legislature, so "legislative coup" like that isn't very likely.
As you mentioned India in a comment, the president there (which less power than in South Korea), is indirectly elected by the national Parliament and the legislatures of the states. So, in that case it makes some sense that the removal process, which is more like a recall, happens at the same level. The US is probably the most special case, where the 'assembly' that formally elects the president is somewhat hard to ascertain. The Electoral College represents the will of the general electorate (so that's one level of indirection already), but their votes are further filtered by the actual legislature. So, in theory, the legislature in the US could also do a coup on that level by arbitrarily rejecting votes from some states etc. (mechanisms for invalidating flawed elections exist in other countries, of course. In some, it's again ultimately in the hands of the judiciary, for better or worse.
As for a claim in some comments under the Q that this isn't common, it may be true in North America. But:

Most European countries use the judicial model where the President is removed from office at the decision of a judicial authority.


Separation of powers does not generally mean that only the legislature can judge themselves. It is meant that judges will not interfere in what is purely a political decission.
For example, a local government can setup a tax on, say, gas. As long as that tax does not break any law(*1), a judge cannot overturn it just because they think it would be a bad thing for the economy. Similarly, neither the executive nor the legislature can jail someone who a judge acquits. But if a politician goes in front of a camara and shots someone, then it could be a judge who will decide if there has been a crime and what the punishment would be.
So, in many countries, criminal (and civil) liabilities of members of the executive and the legislature are dealt by the judges(*2).
Of course, there is always a risk of using the judiciary system to interfere with politicians:

some wealthy interest groups can try to continously sue a politician they do not like even with bogus claim, in the hope of causing him severe economic and time costs.

a rogue judge may decide to support those accusations, even if it is obvious that later on his findings would be reverted on appeal.


To avoid this, a degree of protection is sought by giving members of the executive and legislature the recourse to stop the judicial proceedings. The exact implementation may vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction.
For example, in Spain, possible criminal cases against protected people (aforados) are sent immediately to a higher tribunal (Tribunal Suprempo) in order to minimize rogue judges moving baseless cases forward. If that tribunal does actually charge the aforado, then it asks the Parliament to remove the immunity, and the affected person has the opportunity to make his case before the Parliament and try to convince it that immunity should not be lifted because the case is just a political witch hunt.
(*1) For example, if it is a city government setting the tax but the state government forbids cities from establishing those taxes.
(*2) IMO it is better that way, because in the end of the day the judges are the ones with the formation and experience to conduct trials.

To be clear. The objective of immunity is not to protect legislative or executive from the judiaciary power, but from abuses of it.

"legislative" is an adjective. The noun, and the branch of government, is the legislature.

@SteveMelnikoff fixed that, thank you.


While impeachment is often viewed as a political process, the involvement of the judiciary helps ensure that the decision is not made arbitrarily. In some democracies, the judiciary has a role in ensuring that impeachment is grounded in law rather than political bias. The judiciary's role acts as a safeguard, ensuring that the legislature does not remove officials for purely political reasons, and that laws are followed when determining whether the president has violated constitutional or legal duties.
The inclusion of the judiciary in the process serves as a check on legislative power. The legislature can propose impeachment, but the judiciary, particularly in the form of a constitutional court, ensures that the decision adheres to legal standards. This prevents the legislature from making arbitrary decisions based on political motivations, ensuring that the president can only be removed if a law has been broken or the constitutional duties violated.
In South Korea, the president can only be removed if they’ve broken the law, which provides a clear legal framework for impeachment. The constitutional court's role is to determine whether the president’s actions justify impeachment based on legal grounds. This system of checks and balances ensures fairness and prevents the legislature from overreaching. Additionally, involving the judiciary helps maintain legitimacy in the process, avoiding potential misuse of power and ensuring that the decision reflects legal and constitutional principles.


Welcome aboard. Great answer, but could you cite some references for #3?  Specifically the limitation on laws needing to have been broken and the court's role.
